# Using T5 model's tokenizer into Pegasus Model

Tags: nlp, neural-network, tokenize, transformer-model, huggingface

I'm working on an NLP text summarization project for Bengali Language. I would like to use the Pegasus model from Huggingface. Unfortunately, Pegasus is only trained on English language. So, the tokenizer of the model is not available for Bengali language. Can I use T5 model's tokenizer into the Pegasus model because T5 has tokenizer available for Bengali Language? If I can, in that case, what extra precautions should I follow? Because after running the model for several epochs and it stops at 20 because of early stopping and The Rouge scores are very poor.

This is what I want to do:

```
    type heretokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("csebuetnlp/banglat5")
    model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-cnn_dailymail")
    model = model.to(device)
```

The kernel runs successfully but I am getting this message after running the kernel:

You are using the default legacy behaviour of the <class 'transformers.models.t5.tokenization_t5.T5Tokenizer'>. This is expected, and simply means that the `legacy` (previous) behavior will be used so nothing changes for you. If you want to use the new behaviour, set `legacy=False`. This should only be set if you understand what it means, and thouroughly read the reason why this was added as explained in https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/24565
Some weights of PegasusForConditionalGeneration were not initialized from the model checkpoint at google/pegasus-cnn_dailymail and are newly initialized: ['model.decoder.embed_positions.weight', 'model.encoder.embed_positions.weight']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.